# get image url from array

Tags: php, url, preg-match-all

I want to get image url from array.

```
    $img_link = "http://testserver1.com:8080/test%20messages%20and%20so%20on&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center&quot;&gt;&lt;img width=&quot;396&quot; height=&quot;342&quot; src=&quot;http://testserver2.com/photos/5186145181.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; style=&quot;border: medium none&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br /&gt;test messages and so on &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;"
```

I want to grab image url "http://testserver2.com/photos/5186145181.jpg", and put this into "img_link_results".

```
$img_linkA = explode(' ', $img_link); 
$img_link_results = array(); 
foreach($img_linkA as $img_link) { 
    if(preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', trim($img_link))) { 
        $img_link_results[] = trim($img_link); 
        if (preg_match('#^http:\/\/(.*)\.(gif|png|jpg)$#i', $img_link_results, $tmp)){ 
            $img_link_results = $tmp; 
        }           
    } 
} 
//show results 
echo "<img src='$img_link_results' width='100px' height='100px'>".'<br />';
foreach($img_link_results as $val){ 
    echo "<img src='$img_link_results' width='100px' height='100px'>".'<br />';
}
```

However, the the result at web page is "Array".

Please let me know what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing `$img_link_results` which is an array. You need to use `$val`, the array element as follows:

```
//show results 
foreach($img_link_results as $val){ 
    echo "<img src='$val' width='100px' height='100px'>".'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
echo "<img src='$img_link_results' width='100px' height='100px'>".'<br />';
```

try using `$val`instead

```
echo "<img src='$val' width='100px' height='100px'>".'<br />';
```

Comment: So if you update your question with this new correction, what is the new output?

Answer (score 0):

Add in `var_dump($img_link_results);` and you'll see that it's empty.

```
//output
array(0) {
}
```

Something is broken further up.

Demo here: http://codepad.org/gHKtBbtd

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found this error. Please let me know hot to resolve this error.

Comment: So I changed 
`code`
        if(preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', trim($img_link))) { 
`code`  
into,
`code`
        if(preg_match('/<img[^>]+>/i', trim($img_link))) { 
`code`
then, I got,
`code`
        <img height="100" src="" width="100" /><br />  
`code`