# Overlapping Images from Array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

I am trying to make a planner that allows you to select a wallpaper by season. Currently I'm working on fall and if you click on fall, you can see all of the alerts are different (each url from my array is shown). But, when those alerts go away, I see only one wallpaper. I want all of the wallpapers to show up when fall is clicked on not just one (so user can see all options). I want them to be in a grid view (similar to a photo gallery on iPhones but have the images a little spread out). I'm confused on what I'm doing wrong because the alerts show all url's so I'm not sure if they images are over top of each other. I tried adding margin but that didn't work either.

Here is my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marvel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>PLANNER</header>
  <div id="menu">


    <button id="fall" onclick="seasonFall()">FALL</button>
    <button id="spring" onclick="seasonSpring()">SPRING</button>
    <button id="summer" onclick="seasonSummer()">SUMMER</button>
    <button id="winter" onclick="seasonWinter()">WINTER</button>
    <button id="lock" onclick="defaultButton()">DEFAULT WALLPAPER</button>


  </div>

  <script>
    var fall = [
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3216349/pexels-photo-3216349.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3150553/pexels-photo-3150553.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/589840/pexels-photo-589840.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
    ];

    function seasonFall() {

      for (var i = 0; i < fall.length; i++) {
        var test = document.createElement('div');
        test.id = "test";
        test.innerHTML = document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + fall[i] + "')";
        document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
        document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        document.body.style.backgroundSize = "300px 300px";
        document.body.style.margin = "30px";
        alert(test.innerHTML);
      }
    }

    function defaultButton() {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/3689659/pexels-photo-3689659.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260')";
      document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
      document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
      document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
    }
  </script>

  <style>
    /* PLANNER HEADER AT TOP */
    
    header {
      font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    /* WALLPAPER MENU */
    
    #menu {
      font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
      font-size: 100px;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      grid-area: menu;
    }
    /* SEASON BUTTONS */
    
    button {
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      height: 25px;
      display: block;
      margin: 20px;
      width: 160px;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

I found similar questions but they used other languages:

- [Load images in grid view from Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894572/load-images-in-grid-view-from-url) (Java)
- [get image url from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427694/get-image-url-from-array) (Php)

Comment: So what's the question exactly?

Comment: I have edited my question to better explain what I'm trying to do @DenisG.Labrecque

Comment: @charmy, can you post a photo/sketch of the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the background image of the document body in every iteration in the method `seasonFall`.

Please, try something like this:

```html
 
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marvel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>PLANNER</header>
  <div id="menu">


    <button id="fall" onclick="seasonFall()">FALL</button>
    <button id="spring" onclick="seasonSpring()">SPRING</button>
    <button id="summer" onclick="seasonSummer()">SUMMER</button>
    <button id="winter" onclick="seasonWinter()">WINTER</button>
    <button id="lock" onclick="defaultButton()">DEFAULT WALLPAPER</button>


  </div>

  <div id="wrapper">

  </div>

  <script>
    var fall = [
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3216349/pexels-photo-3216349.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3150553/pexels-photo-3150553.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/589840/pexels-photo-589840.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
    ];

    function seasonFall() {

      for (var i = 0; i < fall.length; i++) {
        // Please, excuse the code, is just for give you the idea
        // Ideally you must use CSS to set as much of these properties as 
        // you can once you have a clear idea of how to organize your grid
        var test = document.createElement('div');
        test.id = "test" + i;
        test.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + fall[i] + "')";
        test.style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
        test.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        test.style.backgroundSize = "300px 300px";
        test.style.margin = "30px";
        test.style.width = "300px";
        test.style.height = "300px";
        wrapper.appendChild(test);
      }
    }

    function defaultButton() {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/3689659/pexels-photo-3689659.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260')";
      document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
      document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
      document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
    }
  </script>

  <style>
    /* PLANNER HEADER AT TOP */
    
    header {
      font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    /* WALLPAPER MENU */
    
    #menu {
      font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
      font-size: 100px;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      grid-area: menu;
    }
    /* SEASON BUTTONS */
    
    button {
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      height: 25px;
      display: block;
      margin: 20px;
      width: 160px;
    }

    #wrapper {
      margin-left: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

The idea is create a series of div elements and set the background properties of them.

You can organize these divs in a grid with the number of columns and rows that you consider appropriate, for instance, just including further loops in the `seasonFall` method and adjusting the margin and position of them.

Comment: Could you please explain how the background image of the document body was being overridden yet the alerts were different? I'm confused because even though the I was only getting 1 image on my page, the alerts always had different url's. The main thing you changed was the id and added the index so each is different. I understand why thats needed but the different alerts is still confusing me

Comment: Of course, and sorry for the late reply. In every loop iteration you are creating a div element. You are setting its ```innerHTML``` property to values of the form ```"url('" + fall[i] + "')"```. When you alert the value of this property at the end loop you are obtaining exactly this value, a different value for every image. But when you set this property you are also setting the value of the ```backgroundImage``` ```body``` style property. This property could only have one value. In every iteration, but the last one, you overwrite it. This is why the last image is the one presented.